Is there a way to use the capture group index as the replacement within a regular expression?
I am using Total Commander file rename utility, and the file names contain dates, for example
May/04/2021

I want to normalize dates and make them sortable by formatting them as YYYY-MM-DD, so have the following regular expression:
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\/(\d\d?)\/((\d\d)?(\d\d))
#\1  \2  \3  \4  \5  \6  \7  \8  \9  \10 \11 \12  <--- index of matched capture group text

# possible alternative regex:
((Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))\/(\d\d?)\/((\d\d)?(\d\d))

In the replacement string, instead of using the actual captured text in the group (in this case, May) I want to replace it with the index number of the captured text within the group, which in this case would be 5, such that the final result would be:
2021-05-04


Is there a way to access/use the index of the captured text within the capture group instead of just the captured text?
And is there a way to format it as 00 instead of just 0?

(I suspect a script may be the only way to do this, but if there is some special regular expression syntax I am unaware of I'd like to find out).

not that im aware of, but being only 12, you can always do /Jan/01/, /Feb/02/, ...

(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) is just one capture group. If you want 12 capture groups, you have to put parentheses around each alternative: (Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|...

This will be much easier in a scripting language. They have date parsing libraries, you can also use an associative array to map month names to numbers, etc.

Now you have two problems

Agree with Barmar: Rather than string manipulation, parse date with MMM-DD-YYYY format, then render it with YYYY-MM-DD format.

@PerdiEstaquel I don't quite following what you are suggesting.

@Barmar I get what you mean, but your suggestion is just another way of capturing. Ultimately it comes down to: is there a way to use a map or conditional if within a regular expression...maybe time to dust off my Regular Expression book again...and, yes, I am fully aware I now have two problems ;)

@Bohemian I can't, this is just a regex in Total Commander for file renaming, which is why I was wondering if there is anything built into the regex engine that can do this....it would be one of the more esoteric regular expression use cases, for certain....

Perdi is referring to using a regex to replace each month, e.g. /from/to/. No idea if Total Commander supports this in its regex implementation.

I would not use a regex at all. Convert each string to a date object using a format string (e.g. in C--where it was born--and other languages, '%b/%d/%Y' for 'May/04/2021'. Once you have a date object it's simple to format it as desired with another format string (e.g., '%Y-%m-%d' for '2021-05-04'). Of course, some preprocessing may be needed if dates are not always expressed in the same format (e.g., 'May/04/2021' in one place and 'Sep/18/22' in another).

Total Commander uses the free Delphi library TRegExpr by Andrey V. Sorokin. So, no way, it does not support conditional replacement. You will need to run 12 replacements for each month. Or simply write a PowerShell script to do the replacing as you need.

In general, regular expression find/replace can just do literal copying. You can rearrange things by using back-references in the replacement string, but there's no computation available to perform transformations like this.

I just did a find replace for each month:

